# How to get the build history in Jenkins using its API?

Tags: jenkins

I want to retrieve the build history (List of completed builds) of a job in Jenkins using Jenkins API. Which URL I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
https://<jenkins_host>/job/<job_name>/api/xml?tree=allBuilds[id]
```

This will return you all the ids of all builds under the `<job_name>`

EDIT:
To get all builds of all jobs:

```
https://<jenkins_host>/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,allBuilds[id]]
```

Caution here, this will be a very very huge files as you may have lots of jobs and lots of builds for each job.

Comment: Is there any way to get the build history from the dashboard[All] view? That way I can get all the build history from the Jenkins rather than going by jobs.

Comment: @JackSparow yes there is. I have updated the answer for that.

Comment: This doesn't list jobs in folders or builds in multibranch projects.

Comment: when you are in folders your url would look something like the following: `http://<jenkins_host>/job/<folder_name>/job/<job_name>/api/xml?tree=allBuilds[id]` You have to parse inside the folder from the list of all builds of job.