# How to get the build history of the jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I  want to retrieve the build history (List of completed builds) of a job which is present inside the folder in Jenkins using Jenkins API. Which URL I should use?

https://<jenkins_host>/job/<job_name>/api/xml?tree=allBuilds[id]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the build history in Jenkins using its API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478598/how-to-get-the-build-history-in-jenkins-using-its-api)